# Select all where one column is false in Doctrine (Symfony 2)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I've code in my controller:

```
$categories = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Categories')->findAll();
```

In default this return all data from my table, but I want return only records where collumn "cenzored" is 0. How can i do it without make another entity?

My Table looks that:

```
cid | integer | auto_increment
name | varchar(50)
cenzored | boolean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `findBy` instead and add some information for the `WHERE`-clause using an array:

```
[…]->findBy(array('cenzored' => false));
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to use `[…]->findByCenzored(false);` in this case?

Comment: Hey @cheesemacfly absolutely right. It will work too in this case. It won't work in a case where the property name has one or more underscores - only as a note.